# Jquery ajax post request not working using jersey

Tags: jquery, ajax, jersey

I am trying to make post request using jQuery but is not working. My jquery code :

```
$.ajax({    
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    url : formURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(contactLogin),
    dataType: 'json',
    /* contentType:'application/json', */
    success: function(data) {
        // window.location="userHomePage.html";
        window.alert("Login successful..!")
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.alert("Login NOT successful..!")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
    }   
});
```

But response is not getting captured in success tag. From press login from login page, i am getting response in error tag :

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "Login failure",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
}
```

Whenever I am checking with correct user details, I am getting response in error tag with the below header.

```
{
    "readyState": 0,
    "responseText": "",
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "error"
}
```

Also my jersey server is below :

```
@POST
@Path("/Login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String loginVerification(JSONObject json) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String email = json.optString("email");
    String password = json.optString("password");

    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    boolean success = db.checkCustomerDetails(email, password);

    if (success)
    {
        return "Login successful";
    }
    else
        return "Login failure";
}
```

Can someone please help me out here? Many thanks

Comment: the server do not resturn json... so remove `dataType: 'json'` and `'Accept': 'application/json'`, from your ajax call.

Comment: Still it is not working.....same output